# Multiple nested script bundles

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have angularjs application on ASP.NET MVC. Issue is that Razor renders `@Script.Bundle()` many times
Here is actual F12 source

    `<html ng-app="app">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link href="/Assets/Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div ng-controller="mainCtrl" class="ng-scope">
    <!-- ngView:  --><div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 tabs-view overflow ng-scope" ng-      class="{reverse: reverse}" ng-view="">
            <meta charset="utf-8" class="ng-scope">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" class="ng-scope">
            <title class="ng-scope">Администрация</title>
            <link href="/Assets/Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" class="ng-scope">
            <div>
                <div>test text</div>
            </div>
            <script src="/Assets/jquery/jquery.min.js" class="ng-scope"></script>
            <script src="/Assets/ng/angular.min.js" class="ng-scope"></script>
            <script src="/Assets/ng/angular-sanitize.min.js" class="ng-scope"></script>
            <script src="/Assets/app/app.js" class="ng-scope"></script>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="/Assets/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Assets/ng/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Assets/ng/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Assets/app/app.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>`

This is ommited version, but as you can see in the ng-view, razor renders bundles again, so there is error saying angular tried load again. Cannot understand why this happening.

`_Layout.cshtml (The only layout. @script bundles located here)
             |____ Home/Index.cshtml (nav bar wrapper with ng-view inside)
                                  |______ App/Index.cshtml (page from F12Tool)`

I dont know what to include for your consideration, ask if need more information
**Razor markup of _Layout.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <title>Администрация</title>
  @Styles.Render("~/Assets/Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css")
</head>
<body>
  @RenderBody()
</body>
@Scripts.Render("~/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/ng")
</html>
```

**Razor markup of Home/Index**

```
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  </div>
<div>
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

**Razor markup of App/Index**

```
<div><div>testig text</div></div>
```

**MVC controller Home**

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // GET: Main
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

** MVC Controller App

```
public class AppController: Controller {
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }
 }
```

Comment: can you provide razor markup?

Comment: Can you also show the MVC controller that is rendering this?

Comment: when angular route asks page controller gives full _Layout.cshtml, and that renders bundles again inside ng-view. can be solved with `return PartialView()`, but still not clear is that way good?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're sticking with .cshtml rather than plain .html templates? You could add a filter that renders a partial only when the request is an AJAX request. But just returning PartialView is acceptable I would say.

Comment: yes, was thinking about that, but seems angular route works different way, `Request.IsAjaxRequest()` returns false everytime

Comment: checked that, it doesnt call `HomeController` which is `return View()`, turns out that ajax request of **angular** route is not ajax, it's something different?

Comment: @user2308005 do you use `_viewstart.cshtml`?

Comment: i solved with IsAjaxRequest(). Everything is fine with angular route, just was checking Request in wrong controller, btw how to close question?